# Wowza historic statistic API actual data is empty array

Tags: wowza

I use Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.1 . I create an application for each client. I need to get bandwidth usage of application to limit bandwidth. I am looking for a way to get bandwidth usage.

I looked API, there is an operation to get historic statistic information about application but it returns empty array for actual datas. It only provides min, max and average values. I query from `v2/servers/{serverName}/vhosts/{vhostName}/applications/vod/monitoring/historic` the response is as below:

```
object(stdClass)[293]
  public 'actual' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'average' => 
    array (size=25)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[294]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T16:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[295]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T17:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[296]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T18:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[297]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T19:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[298]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T20:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[299]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T21:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      6 => 
        object(stdClass)[300]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T22:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      7 => 
        object(stdClass)[301]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T23:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      8 => 
        object(stdClass)[302]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      9 => 
        object(stdClass)[303]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T01:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      10 => 
        object(stdClass)[304]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T02:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      11 => 
        object(stdClass)[305]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T03:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      12 => 
        object(stdClass)[306]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T04:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      13 => 
        object(stdClass)[307]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T05:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      14 => 
        object(stdClass)[308]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T06:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      15 => 
        object(stdClass)[309]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T07:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      16 => 
        object(stdClass)[310]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T08:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      17 => 
        object(stdClass)[311]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T09:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      18 => 
        object(stdClass)[312]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T10:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      19 => 
        object(stdClass)[313]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T11:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      20 => 
        object(stdClass)[314]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T12:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      21 => 
        object(stdClass)[315]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T13:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      22 => 
        object(stdClass)[316]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T14:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      23 => 
        object(stdClass)[317]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T15:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      24 => 
        object(stdClass)[318]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T16:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
  public 'min' => 
    array (size=25)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[319]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T16:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[320]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T17:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[321]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T18:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[322]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T19:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[323]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T20:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[324]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T21:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      6 => 
        object(stdClass)[325]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T22:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      7 => 
        object(stdClass)[326]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T23:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      8 => 
        object(stdClass)[327]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      9 => 
        object(stdClass)[328]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T01:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      10 => 
        object(stdClass)[329]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T02:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      11 => 
        object(stdClass)[330]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T03:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      12 => 
        object(stdClass)[331]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T04:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      13 => 
        object(stdClass)[332]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T05:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      14 => 
        object(stdClass)[333]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T06:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      15 => 
        object(stdClass)[334]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T07:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      16 => 
        object(stdClass)[335]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T08:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      17 => 
        object(stdClass)[336]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T09:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      18 => 
        object(stdClass)[337]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T10:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      19 => 
        object(stdClass)[338]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T11:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      20 => 
        object(stdClass)[339]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T12:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      21 => 
        object(stdClass)[340]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T13:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      22 => 
        object(stdClass)[341]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T14:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      23 => 
        object(stdClass)[342]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T15:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      24 => 
        object(stdClass)[343]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T16:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
  public 'max' => 
    array (size=25)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[344]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T16:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[345]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T17:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[346]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T18:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[347]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T19:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      4 => 
        object(stdClass)[348]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T20:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      5 => 
        object(stdClass)[349]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T21:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      6 => 
        object(stdClass)[350]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T22:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      7 => 
        object(stdClass)[351]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-30T23:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      8 => 
        object(stdClass)[352]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      9 => 
        object(stdClass)[353]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T01:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      10 => 
        object(stdClass)[354]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T02:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      11 => 
        object(stdClass)[355]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T03:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      12 => 
        object(stdClass)[356]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T04:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      13 => 
        object(stdClass)[357]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T05:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      14 => 
        object(stdClass)[358]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T06:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      15 => 
        object(stdClass)[359]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T07:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      16 => 
        object(stdClass)[360]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T08:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      17 => 
        object(stdClass)[361]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T09:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      18 => 
        object(stdClass)[362]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T10:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      19 => 
        object(stdClass)[363]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T11:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      20 => 
        object(stdClass)[364]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T12:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      21 => 
        object(stdClass)[365]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T13:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      22 => 
        object(stdClass)[366]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T14:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      23 => 
        object(stdClass)[367]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T15:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
      24 => 
        object(stdClass)[368]
          public 'dateTime' => string '2016-05-31T16:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'data' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
```

Is there any problem with my configuration? Or am I wrong about meaning of data inside actual entry?